# application:openUrl doesn't get called when using GIDSignIn

Tags: ios, firebase, oauth-2.0, google-signin, gidsignin

Here's how my AppDelegate looks like:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,GIDSignInDelegate {
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    if let error = error {
        // ...
        return
    }

    guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
    let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken,
                                                   accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
}

//For ios 9.0 or above
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any])
    -> Bool {

        return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                                 sourceApplication:options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                                 annotation: [:])
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication:

    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                             sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                             annotation: annotation)
}
```

I added a GIDSignIn button in my storyboard and in my ViewController I assign the UIDelegate to it:

```
class LoginRegisterViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate,GIDSignInUIDelegate {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    bindUIDelegate()
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self

            //registerForKeyboardNotifications()
}
.......
```

When I clicked the GIDSignInButton, it pop up a Google Signin page and then I entered my credential and hit login. Then it directs me back to my app.

I insert a break point in the AppDeletgate.sign() method, I can see it does get hit after it redirects back to the app. But I DON'T see my application:openurl method get called even when I put a break point in it.

So my question is: when does that method get hit? It's said that at the end of authentication process from here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin. But I'm not seeing it gets hit and seems like the AppDeletgate.sign() still works fine even though I remove the application:openurl method.

Comment: have you added call back url

Comment: You mean the URL Schema in the app? I do have it set to Revert Client ID. Or do you mean if I have code to call back the url explicitly? Nope, I don't call the url explicitly in my code. I'm following the guide in firebase and it doesn't say anything about it. @DevilDecoder

Comment: yep that url scheme in app you dont have to code any thing

Comment: @DevilDecoder Yes I did. I wonder if the AppDeletgate.sign() called first or the application:openurl called first? I'm pretty sure AppDeletgate.sign()  is called but the other one not. And I couldn't find any doc about it.

Answer (score 2):

This was confusing me as well, so did some digging. The general steps involved are the following:
(1) App starts the browser
(2) User goes through auth flow on browser
(3) Browser redirects to you app's URL scheme
(4) IOS detects scheme and instead of opening the URL in browser, it knows to open your app and pass the url (containing the auth tokens) to it.

I guess previously, the result of step (4) was IOS opening your app with the `application(...)` entry point, passing in the `url` containing the token. You would then manually call `GIDSignIn.handle(url)`. Looking at the [code](https://github.com/google/GoogleSignIn-iOS/blob/20b21a1997abb13c9e9a7730461c8ae4cbaeb309/GoogleSignIn/Sources/GIDSignIn.m#L169), we see that `handle(url)` calls `resumeExternalUserAgentFlowWithUrl`. This latter method is part of the AppAuth library which is what Google Sign In uses behind the scenes.

Currently, however, the AppAuth library does things differently. Instead of opening a generic browser session, it uses the [ASWebAuthenticationSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/aswebauthenticationsession) API provided by IOS to open Safari. With this approach, instead of opening your app with `application(...)`, the `ASWebAuthenticationSession` will call a `completionHandler` it was created with.

Looking at the AppAuth library [code](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/blob/98ed5e15ceedcacc0b3fd6c3521a22411acc2212/Source/AppAuth/iOS/OIDExternalUserAgentIOS.m#L107). We see that it is this completionHandler that now calls `resumeExternalUserAgentFlow`

TLDR: Instead of opening generic browser session, google sign in now uses ASWebAuthenticationSession which opens Safari to complete your auth flow. When the auth flow completes with a redirect to your app url, instead of IOS opening your app with `application(url)`, the ASWebAuthenticationSession will directly invoke a callback method. Google Sign In implements this callback method for you to handle the resulting url.

Note: ASWebAuthenticationSession has some security benefits. Namely, w. the old approach, someone else could register to handle your own url scheme with their app. This means their app would get the token. However, ASWebAuthenticationSession guarantees the callback on "your app" will be called even if someone else has registered their app w. same url scheme. Pretty cool stuff.